# Java how to Modify IP Address that was input as a string

Tags: java, string, ip, subnet

I have a program that will take a LAN IP provided, I then need to be able to modify just the last octet of the IP's, the first 3 will remain the same based on what was input in the LAN IP Text Field.

For example:
User enter 192.168.1.97 as the LAN IP I need to be able to manipulate the last octet "97", how would I go about doing that so I can have another variable or string that would have say 192.168.1.100 or whatever else i want to set in the last octet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String ip = "192.168.1.97";

// cut the last octet from ip (if you want to keep the . at the end, add 1 to the second parameter
String firstThreeOctets = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf(".")); // 192.168.1

String lastOctet = ip.substring(ip.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); // 97
```

Then, if you want to set the last octet to 100, simply do:

```
String newIp = firstThreeOctet + ".100"; // 192.168.1.100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods

```java
public static byte getLastOctet(String ip) {
    String octet = ip.substring (ip.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    return Byte.parseByte(octet);
}

public static String setLastOctet(String ip, byte octet) {
    return ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf ('.') + 1) + octet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the number at the end of the input.

```
String ipAddress = "192.168.1.97";
String newIpAddress = ipAddress.replaceFirst("\\d+$", "100")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) as follows.  Doing it this way validates the input string and octet value.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```java
static IPv4Address change(String str, int lastOctet) {
    IPv4Address addr = new IPAddressString(str).getAddress().toIPv4();
    IPv4AddressSegment segs[] = addr.getSegments();
    segs[segs.length - 1] = new IPv4AddressSegment(lastOctet);
    return new IPv4Address(segs);
}

IPv4Address next = change("192.168.1.97", 100);
System.out.println(next);
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.100
```